# optional number property vs number | undefined property

Tags: typescript

```
figure?: number; // optional parameter
```

and

```
figure: number | undefined; // union type
```

When they are used as properties of a class, when should they be used in which use case?

Comment: Aren't they identical declarations?

Comment: thats my question! I could not imagine that a language designer offers  really different ways doing the same.

Answer (score 3):

> When they are used as properties of a class, when should they be used in which use case

- Use `figure?` when you may or may not assign a value to it. Reading it will be `undefined` but listing props of the obj will not show this prop.
- Use `figure: number | undefined` when you will *definitely* assign it ... even though you might assign it to `undefined`. Listing props of an instance will not list this property.

## Summary

Read it as it says . Optional assignment vs. Definite assignment (even though it might be assigned undefined).

## Personal

I would use definite assignment as JavaScript VMs behave better when properties are declared up front.

Comment: `figure: number | null` can be interesting as well. Listing props of an instance will list this property.